# Getting value of Enum with Description Attribute of it

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum with Description attributes like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Name1 = 1,
    [Description("Here is another")]
    HereIsAnother = 2,
    [Description("Last one")]
    LastOne = 3
}
```

I have value of "Last one" that is 3

What is the code that return that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
int lastOneValue = (int) MyEnum.LastOne;
```

This code returns the value 2 instead of "LastOne"

```
string lastOneString = MyEnum.LastOne.ToString();
```

This code returns "LastOne" as a string value

```
MyEnum mynum = MyEnum.LastOne;
```

This code creates new object of `MyEnum` and sets his value to 'LastOne'

Comment: Vishal might have been talking about the Description, as how to get that.